# How can I place the label to the left of the gauge?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, highcharts

I am trying to place the zero number outside the gauge, but I don't know how to do it, I can't use the x & y options because the position of the plotLine is always changing so I need the zero to move together with the plotLine and always on the outside.[this is a gauge where the zero is higher than the start of the gauge.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EInZP.png)[in this case the gauge is right where the gauge starts, here you can see how the zero is positioned.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWeyK.png)

Here I will leave the part of the code that I consider relevant

```
    yAxis: {
      reversed: false,
      min: min || 0,
      max: max || 1,
      lineWidth: 0,
      tickInterval: 0,
      tickWidth: 0,
      tickColor: "transparent",
      minorTickInterval: null,
      zIndex: 4,
      tickAmount: 2,
      title: {
        y: -90,
      },
      labels: {
        y: 20,
        distance: -25,
        style: {
          color: activeColor, // muiTheme.palette.common.coal[0],
          fontSize: "14px",
        },
      },
      plotBands: [
        {
          from: plotBandValueFrom,
          to: plotBandValueTo,
          borderColor: "#000",
          backgroundColor: "transparent",
          borderWidth: 2,
          thickness: "100%",
          outerRadius: "80%",
          innerRadius: "60%",
          zIndex: 10,
        },
      ],
      plotLines: [
        {
          value: 0,
          zIndex: 5,
          width: 4,
          color: "#000",
          label: {
            text: 0,
            verticalAlign: "top",
            textAlign: "center",
            style: {
              color: "#000",
              fontSize: "10px",
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I suggest that you do not post images as links; instead, just paste where  you want it to show up.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to position the label in this way using properties from the API. However, you can use the `chart.events.render()` callback to update the position with your own logic. The demo below is not perfect but is an example of how this can be achieved.

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ud9rjmfL/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render